# CodeceptJS how to return an array of elements? - similarly to querySelectorAll

Tags: javascript, automation, codeceptjs

Writing the following command in the console:

```
document.querySelectorAll("[type='checkbox']")
```

Returns:

```
NodeList(12) [input.jss719, input.jss719, input.jss719, input.jss719, input.jss719, input.jss719, input.jss719, input.jss719, input.jss719, input.jss719, input.jss719, input.jss719]
```

This is exactly what I want to achieve in Codeceptjs, so I can later loop through the elements.

I've tried creating custom functions like:

```
 allSelector: function (selector)  {
  return Array.from.document.querySelectorAll(selector)
}
```

However, I keep getting `null` when console logging:

```
  let checkboxes =  (await I.grabAttributeFrom("[type='checkbox']"))

  console.log(checkboxes)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the attribute name, for example 'name'

```
let checkboxes =  (await I.grabAttributeFrom("[type='checkbox']", "name"))
```